# why is it saying that class is undefined in Java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here what happens to me is that when I tried to see the parent of the "class inner" it is saying `undefined` in the console but when I am doing the same thing with the id it is showing its parent. Why?
Is there any restriction to work with all that stuff? What do we need to do to see the parent with class?

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("inner").parentElement;

console.log(a)

// var a = document.getElementById("inner").parentElement;

// console.log(a)
```

```css
*{
  text-align:center;
}
.outer{
  background:hotpink;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:8em;
  height:400px;
}
.inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
#inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
.a,.b,.c,.d{
  margin-left:6px;
  
  
  background:white;
  width:150px;
  height:130px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <h1>outer box</h1>
    <div class="inner" id="inner">
      <h1></h1>
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object. you need to loop or access the elements like an array, for example:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].parentElement;

console.log(a)

// var a = document.getElementById("inner").parentElement;

// console.log(a)
```

```css
*{
  text-align:center;
}
.outer{
  background:hotpink;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:8em;
  height:400px;
}
.inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
#inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
.a,.b,.c,.d{
  margin-left:6px;
  
  
  background:white;
  width:150px;
  height:130px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <h1>outer box</h1>
    <div class="inner" id="inner">
      <h1></h1>
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns `NodeList` not `Element`.

And `NodeList.parentElement` is not existed so you will get `undefined`.

`NodeList` object is collection of `nodes`. And to get specific node on `index`, you should call `NodeList[index]`.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index ++) {
  console.log(a[index].parentElement);
}
```

```css
*{
  text-align:center;
}
.outer{
  background:hotpink;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:8em;
  height:400px;
}
.inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
#inner{
  background:#FFFF99;
  width:800px;
    height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  
}
.a,.b,.c,.d{
  margin-left:6px;
  
  
  background:white;
  width:150px;
  height:130px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <h1>outer box</h1>
    <div class="inner" id="inner">
      <h1></h1>
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="c">c</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```